# Javers - How to avoid/disable perticular field for the auditing by Javers?

Tags: javers

I am using **Spring Boot Javers Integration** example by taking reference from https://javers.org/documentation/spring-boot-integration/ and https://github.com/javers/organization-structure.git.

I have developed fully working POC which works fine, but fields like `CreatedDate`, `CreatedBy` and `lastUpdateDate` and `LastUpdatedBy` these fields I've audited using Spring `@EnableMongoAuditing` feature. But these fields I don't want to consider for auditing by Javers.

Is there any if we can skip fields for auditing/changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice documentation here: https://javers.org/documentation/domain-configuration/#ignoring-things

**Use property-level**

`@DiffIgnore` or `@ShallowReference` to ignore non-important properties. Alternatively, use `@DiffInclude` to mark all important properties. See property annotations.

**Use class-level**

`@DiffIgnore` , `@ShallowReference` or `@IgnoreDeclaredProperties` (see class annotations).

`@DiffIgnore` is strongest and means I don’t care, just ignore all objects with this type.

`@ShallowReference` is moderate and means Do shallow diff, bother me only when referenced Id is changed.

`@IgnoreDeclaredProperties` is the least radical and means Ignore all properties declared in this class but take care about all inherited properties.